# How To Execute JavaScript inside a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

i want to deactivate Telegram account inside my android app .
my problem is about an ajax form in this site https://telegram.org/deactivate 
i can get the html elements by javascript and set them but i can't run JavaScript codes for many times.
in the other words
i have an application have one edittext that user give self phone number to copy on site and my app click submit buttom on form automatically by JavaScript But when password sent from telegram to user phone number, i can't set this password in new password field of telegram deactivate website.
i use codes of this site: 
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-inject-javascript-into-an-android-web-view-for-a-more-dynamic-ux/

all JavaScript codes execute in onPageFinished method for one time :(
pls help

Comment: i want to deactive user telegram by getting his phone number and password inside my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think execute javascript is the error, but... if you need to execute javascript in your webview use this:

```
  wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: no! 
you dont read my question . i dont need execute JavaScript Codes only 
i want to control ajax html form